# How do I output xml node element using visual studio 2010 code

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have xml doc which I want to read using vb 2010 in debug mode to see if the PetitionerNotification element exist. 
**How do I do this in Visual Studio?** 
**Here is my xml code**

```
<IntegrationCondition Word="BCAPO" Description="BCA PO Notification">
        <NotificationEvent notificationType="ProtectionOrderService" internalProtectionOrderID="218" protectionOrderNumber="1400218" servedByWord="FD0450002" servedByText="Argyle City Attorney" dateServed="10/29/2014" timeServed="" howServedWord="INPERSON" howServedText="In Person" whoWasServedInternalId="704461574" whoWasServed="Guardian" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">ServiceToSend</NotificationEvent>
        <NotificationEvent notificationType="ProtectionOrderService" internalProtectionOrderID="218" protectionOrderNumber="1400218" servedByWord="ABBOTT" servedByText="Abbott House" dateServed="10/27/2014" timeServed="" howServedWord="INPERSON" howServedText="In Person" whoWasServedInternalId="672281003" whoWasServed="Respondent" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">ServiceToSend</NotificationEvent>
        <NotificationEvent notificationType="PetitionerNotification" internalProtectionOrderID="218" protectionOrderNumber="1400218" petitionerEmailAddress="email@email.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">PetitionerNotification</NotificationEvent>
    </IntegrationCondition>
```

**Here is my visual studio code that I need to add if statement to check if the xml has petitionernotification element.**

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Xml
Public Class myUpdates
    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim objMessageProcessor As New MessageProcessor
        Dim objSchemasCollection As New Msc.Integration.MessageBroker.Library.v4.SchemasCollection
        Dim objTransformsCollection As New Msc.Integration.MessageBroker.Library.v4.TransformsCollection
        objMessageProcessor.ProcessInputQueue(False, False, objSchemasCollection, objTransformsCollection)
    End Sub

    Private Class MessageProcessor
        Inherits Msc.Integration.MessageBroker.Library.v4.XmlMessageProcessor
        Protected Overrides Sub ProcessMessage(ByRef aobjBroker As MessageBroker.Library.v4.Broker, _
        ByRef aobjXmlInputDoc As System.Xml.XmlDocument, ByRef aobjInstantiatedObjectsCollection As Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection)
            MyBase.ProcessMessage(aobjBroker, aobjXmlInputDoc, aobjInstantiatedObjectsCollection)

            Dim strCaseNumber As String
            Dim strProtectionOrderNumber As String
            Dim objNameTable As NameTable
            Dim objXMLNameSpaceManager As XmlNamespaceManager
            Dim objXmlServiceNode As XmlNode
            Dim objProtectionOrder As Msc.Integration.Dccis.Library.v4.ProtectionOrder
            Dim objXmlCrossReferenceNode As XmlNode
            Dim objCrossReferenceNumber As Msc.Integration.Dccis.Library.v4.ProtectionOrderCrossReferenceNumber
            Dim intServedPartyID As Integer
            Dim objCaseParties As List(Of Msc.Integration.Dccis.Library.v4.CaseParty)
            Dim dtmDateServed As Date
            Dim blnIncludesTime As Boolean
            Dim objCaseEvent As Msc.Integration.Dccis.Library.v4.CaseEvent
            Dim blnServiceFound As Boolean = False
            Dim objUpdatesList As New List(Of Msc.Integration.Dccis.Library.v4.IApiObject)

            'Validate the message
            aobjBroker.ValidateXmlDocument(aobjXmlInputDoc, "ProtectionOrderLawEnforcementDataExchange_1_0.xsd", "NiemExchanges\ProtectionOrders\Exchange", , True)

            'create a namespace manager used for queries into inputmessage (because of namespace)
            objNameTable = New NameTable
            objXMLNameSpaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(objNameTable)
            objXMLNameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("ext", "http://www.courts.state.dc.us/ProtectionOrderExtension/1.0")
            objXMLNameSpaceManager.AddNamespace("nc", "http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0")

            strCaseNumber = aobjXmlInputDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ext:CourtFileNumber", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
            strProtectionOrderNumber = aobjXmlInputDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ext:ProtectionOrderID", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
            objProtectionOrder = Msc.Integration.Dccis.Library.v4.ProtectionOrder.Get(strCaseNumber, CInt(strProtectionOrderNumber), False)
            objUpdatesList.Add(objProtectionOrder)
            'Process service 
            For Each objXmlServiceNode In aobjXmlInputDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("ext:ProtectionOrderService", objXMLNameSpaceManager)
                If objXmlServiceNode.SelectSingleNode("ext:ProtectionOrderServiceTime", objXMLNameSpaceManager) Is Nothing Then
                    blnIncludesTime = False
                    dtmDateServed = CDate(objXmlServiceNode.SelectSingleNode("ext:ProtectionOrderServiceDate", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText)
                Else
                    blnIncludesTime = True
                    dtmDateServed = CDate(objXmlServiceNode.SelectSingleNode("ext:ProtectionOrderServiceDate", _
                    objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText + " " + objXmlServiceNode.SelectSingleNode("ext:ProtectionOrderServiceTime", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText)
                End If
                intServedPartyID = 0
                If objXmlServiceNode.SelectSingleNode("ext:ProtectionOrderServiceToCode", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText = "Respondent" Then
                    'This must be the respondent
                    intServedPartyID = objProtectionOrder.RespondentInternalPartyID
                    objProtectionOrder.AddService(objXmlServiceNode.SelectSingleNode("ext:ProtectionOrderServiceAgency/nc:OrganizationIdentification/nc:IdentificationID", _
                    objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText, dtmDateServed, blnIncludesTime, objXmlServiceNode.SelectSingleNode("ext:ProtectionOrderServiceTypeCode", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText, intServedPartyID)
                    blnServiceFound = True
                Else
                    'This must be the Guardian
                    objCaseParties = Msc.Integration.DCcis.Library.v4.CaseParty.Get("GRD", strCaseNumber)
                    If objCaseParties.Count = 0 Then
                        aobjBroker.PostMessageWarehouseInformationalMessage("No active guardian found on the case – this service was not added to the protection order.", 1)
                    Else
                        intServedPartyID = objCaseParties.First.Party.InternalID
                    End If
                    If intServedPartyID <> 0 Then
                        objProtectionOrder.AddService(objXmlServiceNode.SelectSingleNode("ext:ProtectionOrderServiceAgency/nc:OrganizationIdentification/nc:IdentificationID", _
                        objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText, dtmDateServed, blnIncludesTime, objXmlServiceNode.SelectSingleNode("ext:ProtectionOrderServiceTypeCode", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText, intServedPartyID)
                        blnServiceFound = True
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            If blnServiceFound Then
                objCaseEvent = New Msc.Integration.DCcis.Library.v4.CaseEvent("IBSERVNOT", Now, False, , strCaseNumber)
                objUpdatesList.Add(objCaseEvent)
            End If
            'Process other identification
            objXmlCrossReferenceNode = aobjXmlInputDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ext:ProtectionOrderOtherIdentification", objXMLNameSpaceManager)
            If Not objXmlCrossReferenceNode Is Nothing Then
                'Check if this ID is already in the protection order
                For Each objCrossReferenceNumber In objProtectionOrder.CrossReferenceNumbers
                    If Not objCrossReferenceNumber.Number = objXmlCrossReferenceNode.SelectSingleNode("nc:IdentificationID", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText And _
                      objCrossReferenceNumber.TypeCodeWord = objXmlCrossReferenceNode.SelectSingleNode("ext:ProtectionOrderOtherIdentificationTypeCode", _
                      objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText Then
                        'Throw New System.Exception("Protection Order " + strProtectionOrderNumber + " already has " + objCrossReferenceNumber.TypeText + " " + objCrossReferenceNumber.Number + " associated with it.")
                        Throw New System.Exception("This Protection Order already has an NCIC Number associated with it.")
                    End If
                Next
                'Add the cross reference
                objProtectionOrder.AddCrossReferenceNumber(objXmlCrossReferenceNode.SelectSingleNode("ext:ProtectionOrderOtherIdentificationTypeCode", _
                objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText, objXmlCrossReferenceNode.SelectSingleNode("nc:IdentificationID", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText)
            End If
            'Save updates
            Msc.Integration.DCcis.Library.v4.Odyssey.SaveUpdates(objUpdatesList)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Comment: The phrase "PetitionerNotification" appears in two different places in your example XML document, but in neither place is it used as the name of an element.  In one place, it is used as the value of the `notificationType` attribute.  In the other place, it's used as the value of a `NotificationEvent` element.  So, which condition do you intend to look for?  Do you want to find the `NotificationEvent` element which has a `notificationType` attribute equaling "PetitionerNotification", or do you want to find the `NotificationEvent` element which has a value of "PetitionerNotification", or both?

Comment: I want to find the NotificationEvent element which has a notificationType attribute equaling "PetitionerNotification"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you intend to insert the condition into your existing code, but here's a simple example that loads that XML document and determines whether or not the element exists.

The following checks to see if a `NotificationEvent` element exists which contains the value "PetitionerNotification":

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("Test.xml")
Dim node As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/IntegrationCondition/NotificationEvent[text()='PetitionerNotification']")
If node IsNot Nothing Then
    ' The node exists
End If
```

And the following checks to see if a `NotificationEvent` element exists which has its `notificationType` attribute set to "PetitionerNotification":

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("Test.xml")
Dim node As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/IntegrationCondition/NotificationEvent[@notificationType='PetitionerNotification']")
If node IsNot Nothing Then
    ' The node exists
End If
```

I'm not sure which condition specifically you are looking for, so take your pick.  Both of the examples above are using conditional statements in XPath to narrow the results of the `SelectSingleNode` method.  The condition is the part between the square brackets.  If you are going to be working with XML much, it will be worth your time to learn more about XPath.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I went with the second one and had to change it some. It worked though.